# How to curl download and extract file only when file is modified?

Tags: batch, curl

my example script (not real one used)

```
if exist dependencies2015.zip (  
    curl -kLO https://obsproject.com/downloads/dependencies2015.zip -f --retry 5 -z dependencies2015.zip  
:: I want 7z extract when curl download newer file only here  
    7z.exe x dependencies2015.zip -y -o.  
) else (  
    curl -kLO https://obsproject.com/downloads/dependencies2015.zip -f --retry 5 -C -  
    7z.exe x dependencies2015.zip -y -o.  
)
```

I want to download and extract a file when it's newer than local copy. (in script, windows) Currently I download and extract file with 7zip. I can skip curl download when local copy is updated. But 7zip doesn't know if file is changed and always extract it.

curl exit code shows different errors, but I don't see status of how operation is completed. Do I miss something, or other way to do what I want.

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Describe the scenario you want to be able to recognize, or two scenarios you want to be able to distinguish between, and what you're trying to do (in more than a single incomplete sentence, please).

Answer (score 0):

I come up with this idea

```
if exist dependencies2015.zip (
    curl -kLo new.zip https://obsproject.com/downloads/dependencies2015.zip -f --retry 5 -z dependencies2015.zip
    if exist new.zip (
        7z.exe x new.zip -y -o.
        move /y new.zip dependencies2015.zip
    )
) else (
    curl -kLO https://obsproject.com/downloads/dependencies2015.zip -f --retry 5 -C -
    7z.exe x dependencies2015.zip -o.
)
```

not perfect as what I want, but it works
fix a typo lol